# How to copy file in macOS terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm in a mac trying to learn terminal and i tried many deferent ways to copy my files and i just get the usual usage: cp [-R [-H | blablabla.

I'm proficient on windows and is super similar to terminal but i'm new here so please help.

I'm trying:
cp /Users/l3ny/OneDrive/PS Settings/Keyboard/l3ny.kys ... /Users/l3ny/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2017/Presets/Keyboard Shortcuts

I did tried with ~ at the beginning of source and destination but failed, also without the .... in between src and des and failed too.

I accomplish this task on windows like this:
Copy-Item "$SDKeyboar" "$CPhKeys" -recurse -force #with the path in a variable obviously.

also do you set var on terminal like this? my_var=longUrlVar . without spaces?

thank you guys. 
[image]

Comment: If you have spaces in your filenames/paths, you must enclose the filename/path in double quotes... `cp "/path/with a space/filename" "/path/also with space/"`

Comment: still nothing please see picture. may it be because I'm using high sierra preview but i don't think so.

Comment: Why have you got three dots in the middle?

Comment: on the documentation says destination folder with dotts. but i took them out and still . please see new picture i uploaded. soory that picture has dots.. but i tried without the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... first set up the source where you are copying from:

```
src="/Users/l3ny/OneDrive/PS Settings/Keyboard/l3ny.kys"
```

then run:

```
ls -l "$src"
```

And it should give you some sensible output. Stop if it doesn't.

Now set up the destination:

```
dst="/Users/l3ny/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2017/Presets/Keyboard Shortcuts"
```

then run:

```
ls -ld "$dst"
```

and it should give you some sensible output. If it doesn't, it probably means the destination directory doesn't exist, in which case, create it with:

```
mkdir -p "$dst"
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
cp "$src" "$dst"
```

Comment: src=“Users/l3ny/OneDrive/PS Settings/Keyboard/l3ny.kys” came no ls: “??: No such file or directory . also my files are here and des exist too.

Comment: Try `cd; cd OneDrive; ls`

Comment: yeah it listed all of m file ok.

Comment: Ok `cd "PS Settings"; ls`

Comment: Ok `cd Keyboard; ls`

Comment: Ok, `ls -l l3ny.kys`

Comment: Mark thanks for helping but you are making me list stuff and I do get the result. But I'm still not able to copy

Comment: There are only very few possibilities. The source files are either not where  you think, or the target directory does not exist.What happened **exactly** when you ran the commands in my answer?

Comment: I made a video is short. see what am doing. thanks https://1drv.ms/v/s!Apgib8uKHOhTgd4sOOsRNgzaBmVpjQ

Comment: Ok, you didn't follow accurately what I said in my answer where I didn't use any options. You also used `cp -r` when the option to recurse is **capital R** not lower-case `r`. Also, if you use the recurse option, your source argument needs to be a directory rather than a file.

Comment: did without recourse still i get error...im gonna give up mac suck really..

Comment: I did I was just listing things. I did get results but when doing the copieng nothing

Comment: Mark thank you. I figured setting -a would copy not just 1 file but all in directory obviously setting the source var only as dir not a single file. 
not with many many files ej..all photoshop scripts and actions to have to drive terminal to the final cp its alot of work. In windows i dont need to do this i just cp "src file" "des folder" but anyways thank you so much man..i will set this to answered. @l3ny

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me

```
mv ~/Desktop/GloryHub.xcodeproj ~/AppleXcodeProjects/pjdigitalpool_ios/GloryHub.xcodeproj
```